I can't use service neither repository inside subscriber page (Nest js)
Here is my service
@Injectable()
export class ReviewService {
 
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Review) private Review: Repository<Review>,
    @InjectRepository(Driver) private Driver: Repository<Driver>,
  ) {}

  async calcAverageRatings(driverId: number) {
    const stats = await this.Review.createQueryBuilder('review')
      .where('review.refCaptain = :driverId', { driverId })
      .select('COUNT(review.id)', 'nRatings')
      .addSelect('AVG(review.rating)', 'avgRating')
      .getRawOne();

    console.log(stats);
  }

what i'm building is a functionality to calculate the average rating for a driver, the calculation must happen each time there is a new review inserted, but when i'm trying to add this service to the subscriber page(using dependency injection) no thing is being read
Here is the subscriber page
@EventSubscriber()
export class ReviewSubscriber implements EntitySubscriberInterface<Review> {
  constructor(private reviewService: ReviewService) {}
  listenTo() {
    return Review;
  }

  async afterInsert(event: InsertEvent<Review>) {
    await this.reviewService.calcAverageRatings(event.entity.refCaptain.id);
  }

what i'm expecting is the logging from the calcAverage function, but this is what happens
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'calcAverageRatings')
    at ReviewSubscriber.afterInsert (/Users/mohamedibrahim/figma-project/src/review/subscribers/review.subscriber.ts:19:30)

and when i tried to log the reviewService inside the subscriber gives me undefined

if you want to have that ReviewSubscriber as a nestjs provider, you must add @Injectable() to it as well. The EventSubscriber decorator factory is from typeorm and so it has nothing to do with nestjs.
